# Create a Excel table with data spread over multiple lines in another table

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Let's say I have a table like following:

[image: My source table]

and I would like to create following table from it:

[image: My prefered target layout]

Any ideas on how to start with this?
I have no clue on how I should even start.
I was thinking of doing this with Excel with VBA but this is no necessity.

This example is to rearrange an SQL output I created, and now I want to rearrange this to a table that has a view that is easy to use for statistics.

Comment: Are you actually using symbols in your result? Or will they be numeric? If you're looking for a numeric result, you should look into Pivot Tables in Excel. If you're actually using symbols (I can't imagine how that would be useful) then it's a different story.

Comment: This is a PIVOT in SQL - maybe do it at that level..

Comment: If Excel is used, refer to [this link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/02/22/vlookup-multiple-values-excel/)

Comment: And to use with Excel VBA, you can use .Find, Match, Variant Array or loops to find a value, then you get the address of that value and manipulate to insert on a new cell

Comment: I just used symbols to represent a kind of value. All the ABC, 123 and +=$ values will just be numeric and alphabetical values like “Player1” “language” “eng”

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. I succeded in what I wanted by using pivot tables.